# How can I make my authentication token work with safety?

Tags: php, react-native, authentication, token

I am making an authentication system with React-Native/PHP/MySQL where you have these steps:

> 1. User Login: The user enters his username and password, a token is generated in the DB and his expiration 5 minutes
> 2. Actions: If the user wants to do any action other than LOGOUT, a POST request is sent to the API with the action and the token
> 3. Check Token: Checks whether the token is valid (exists in the DB) and if it is expired if it is, it renews the expiration time, and
>      performs the action

I have some questions:

> 1. If the token duplicates? It is a 64-character token, but it should always be able to be duplicated
> 2. If someone for some reason obtains this token, that person can do several things in the user's account. So I was thinking about renewing
>      the token generating another expired case, is it the best way?

Is this the best way for a token authentication system?

Comment: Why would you allow token duplication?

Comment: Could I put a while with a SELECT saying if there is a token generated in the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get over with it fast, and it's not something you want to do for fun, but something you need to integrate to your project, then I would go with [OAuth](https://www.oauth.com/) or some similar package, which already exists.

### Otherwise:

1. It's a good practice to make sure that your token is unique. You can set the field for the table as unique, so when you try to save it, but it exists, you will get an error, and you can generate an another one.(1) OR you can create an algorithm which will make sure that the token isn't exists in the database. For this you can use timestamp and maybe userID for the token hash algorithm.

For example:

```
$token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
```

**Why is it good to not let tokes to be duplicated?**

If you have users in your database, admins and clients are used to be stored in the same users table. The difference between them is used to be a role field, which defines if they are guests, clients, admins, nazguls, dementors, ect.

Let's say an admin got a token(123) and later on an another user - maybe a client will get the same token(123). In this case if you check the permissions on an API end-point, for a request, then you have to store the userID with the token, and during the permission check you also have to add an extra condition to check the userID, otherwise the client might will obtain the admin token, and gain access to admin end-points/functions with it.

It's also possible if you don't clear the old tokens immediately after they expire, that during the permission check the checker will return with the outdated token, thus the user will get permission denied.

So it's not necessary, but simpler.

2. For token expiration you have 3 options. These are the following:

   - Short-lived access tokens and long-lived refresh tokens
   - Short-lived access tokens and no refresh tokens
   - Non-expiring access tokens

you can read more about them [here](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/)